# EF 7. Unique values

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EntityFramewok 7 and I need unique fields, but not keys. For example, I have product model:

```
public class Product<TKey> : Entity<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

And I have three products (their names are: *product1*, *product2*, *product3*) in my database. And I want `Name` to be unique. I want to be able to change Name value, and if it is mathces another product name, I want to get mistake (in fact I want to be able to change *product2* to *product5*, but I want to get mistake if I try to change *product2* to *product3*). I have tried to implement this such way:

```
builder.Entity<Product<string>>(b =>
{
    b.HasAlternateKey(p => p.Name);
});
```

In this case, I can not modify `Name` field at all. When I tried to implement this with another approach:

```
builder.Entity<Product<string>>(b =>
{
    b.HasIndex(p => p.Name).IsUnique();
});
```

Whith this code when I changed *product2* to *product3* I have no mistakes and database is updated.

How can I implement such feature? For all this testin I use in memory database. Maybe it is the reason?

Comment: I'm using the second approach with CodeFirst. In my case a unique index is created in the database (SQL-Server). So it's unique. Maybe there is a bug with the in-memory-database. (But I could not find anything on Github.) I also tried your first solution first and found a GitHub entry stating that this is the intended behavior: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3563